# Merge workbooks - take other values ​and add them to column C

Tags: excel, vba, macos

This is a piece of code that takes some values ​​(A1: C5) and pastes them, one below the other, in column B. Obviously, in column A there is the name of the file.

Now, simply, I need to take another content piece (B2: D13) and insert it in column C.
I tried but it doesn't stick anything to me.

```
Sub MergeCode1()
    Dim BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim rnum As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim MySplit As Variant
    Dim FileInMyFiles As Long
    Dim Mybook As Workbook
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim destrange As Range
    Dim SourceRcount As Long

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    BaseWks.Range("A1").Font.Size = 36
    BaseWks.Range("A1").Value = "Please Wait"
    rnum = 3

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Clear MyFiles to be sure that it not return old info if no files are found
    MyFiles = ""

    'Get the files, set the level of folders and extension in the code line below
    Call GetFilesOnMacWithOrWithoutSubfolders(Level:=1, ExtChoice:=0, FileFilterOption:=0, FileNameFilterStr:="")
    'Level                       :  1= Only the files in the folder you select, 2 to ? levels of subfolders
    'ExtChoice               :  0=(xls|xlsx|xlsm|xlsb), 1=xls , 2=xlsx, 3=xlsm, 4=xlsb, 5=csv, 6=txt, 7=all files, 8=(xlsx|xlsm|xlsb), 9=(csv|txt)
    'FileFilterOption     :  0=No Filter, 1=Begins, 2=Ends, 3=Contains
    'FileNameFilterStr  : Search string used when FileFilterOption = 1, 2 or 3

    ' Work with the files if MyFiles is not empty.
    If MyFiles <> "" Then

        MySplit = Split(MyFiles, Chr(13))
        For FileInMyFiles = LBound(MySplit) To UBound(MySplit)

            Set Mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set Mybook = Workbooks.Open(MySplit(FileInMyFiles))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not Mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With Mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C5")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        Mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MySplit(FileInMyFiles)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                Mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next FileInMyFiles
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    BaseWks.Range("A1").Value = "Ready"
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

Many thanks

Comment: If you're pasting A1:C5 in ColB why would you paste B2:D13 in ColC ?  ASlo - it would be useful to post the code you tried, along with a description of any problem you had when running your code.

Comment: @TimWilliams I pasted the code in full, as you requested. I need to paste B2: D13 in ColC because it is a matter of making a comparison of data, but this is not related to the thing in question.

Comment: By "the code you tried" I meant your efforts to make the change you need.  If you copy A1:C5 into ColB it will occupy B:D - how are you then pasting B2:D13 into ColC without overwriting your first paste?

Comment: it was a example. It can also be G8: Z10, it depends on the value I want to capture. I need to copy content, obviously different from the one captured in column B, in other columns. But I need to know what code I have to write to do this and where I have to place it. @TimWilliams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but should be more or less OK:

```
Sub MergeCode1()
    Dim BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim rnum As Long
    Dim MySplit As Variant
    Dim Mybook As Workbook
    Dim src1 As Range, src2 As Range
    Dim destrange As Range
    Dim Rcount As Long
    Dim f

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    BaseWks.Range("A1").Font.Size = 36
    BaseWks.Range("A1").Value = "Please Wait"
    rnum = 3

    MyFiles = ""
    Call GetFilesOnMacWithOrWithoutSubfolders(Level:=1, ExtChoice:=0, _
                          FileFilterOption:=0, FileNameFilterStr:="")

    If MyFiles <> "" Then

        MySplit = Split(MyFiles, Chr(13))
        For Each f In MySplit

            Set Mybook = Workbooks.Open(f)
            Set src1 = Mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:C5")
            Set src2 = Mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("G8:Z10")
            'max # of rows to be added...
            Rcount = Application.Max(src1.Rows.Count, src2.Rows.Count)

            If rnum + Rcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                Mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                Exit For
            Else
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A").Resize(Rcount).Value = f
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "B").Resize(src1.Rows.Count, _
                                                src1.Columns.Count).Value = src1.Value
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "B").Offset(0, src2.Columns.Count) _
                             .Resize(src2.Rows.Count, src2.Columns.Count).Value = src2.Value
                rnum = rnum + Rcount
            End If

            Mybook.Close savechanges:=False
        Next f
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit

    End If

    BaseWks.Range("A1").Value = "Ready"

End Sub
```